# how to make a multiline textbox not accept Enter and Backspace

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, multiline

I have a multiline textbox which shouldn't accept alphabets, numbers, newline(enter key) and backspace. In short, the `textbox.Text` shouldn't be editable. But I do want the textbox to accept two shortcut keys - control and control+R. One way I can make the textbox un-editable is by making it read-only. But then the textbox wont accept any keystroke at all. In short, my shortcuts ( control and control+R) wont work( Control + R) with read-only method.

Can anyone help in this regard. That's all I have to do.

One thing I could do here is not to make the textbox read-only and then restrict the characters(alphabets and digits) that could be inputted in the textbox. With this code:

```
    private void txtResult_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // only modifier keys, escape, enter, backspace etc is accepted now
        e.Handled = !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
    }

    private void txtResult_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control == true)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.R)
            {
                // do something
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

With this technique I can get the shortcuts(control and control+R) working. But the trouble with this method is that Enter and Backspace keys work as well making it possible to edit the text of textbox. How can I specifically restrict Enter and Backspace key being registered from the textbox, but let Control and Escape??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try `SuppressKeyPress = true` ?

```
private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control == true)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.R)
                {
                    // do something
                }
                else
                {
                    //do something
                }
            }
            else
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;


        }
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the Esc key, as requested in the question. It also doesn't prevent the textbox from being modified. Since you don't indicate the presses of the R key are "handled", the textbox control will still see them as input, and type the letter R.

Comment: Thanks. Worked. I'm grateful. Yes there's this minor editing I'd to do since you didn't incorporate the `Esc` function I wanted, as mentioned by @Cody Gray. I think I can edit your code to include that. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Cody Gray, Yes this method works. textbox doesnt get the letter R typed as you suppose. Yes my textbox is still not read-only. Textbox is prevented completely from being modified..

Answer (score 1):

Since you are handling the keys in the KeyDown event handler, why not have your KeyPress handler return that all keystrokes are handled?

So just set e.Handled = true no matter what. I believe the backspace and enter would be interpreted as control characters, also.

Comment: @David Paxson.

Can you give the code itself? I cant understand how to do otherwise

Comment: What's the point of handling the keys in both `KeyDown` and `KeyPress`?

Comment: @Cody Gray, because the following code wont work under `KeyDown` (`KeyDown` has no `KeyChar`)

     e.Handled = !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);

And there's no KeyCode or KeyData under `KeyPress`. Hope you get it..

Comment: @nawfal: Who cares if that works? If you *only* want to catch Ctrl, Ctrl+R, and Esc, you don't need that.

Comment: @Cody Gray,I'm sorry u din get the point. I was talkin bearin in mind that I havent made textBox read-only. If that's the case, I mean that the program wont run at all if I use just 1 eventhandler. Debug wont be successful if I dont employ 2 eventhandlers like I did. For eg, how can I restrict alphabets & digits being typed? I have to use 
`e.Handled = !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);` I suppose. This will show error in KeyDown event. This wont execute. This can be done only under KeyPress.& similarly there's no `e.KeyCode` or `e.KeyData` in KeyPress. Even your answer wont work. I'll comment there

Comment: @nawfal: I still don't get the point. You have a perfectly acceptable solution, but you don't want to use it? Why not? What's wrong with making the textbox readonly? The only problem with it was that you couldn't figure out how to make it work. My answer explains how to make it work. Why did you mention it at all if it's not what you want? Your requirements are **not at all** clear; please edit your question to clarify what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: @Cody Gray, I clearly explained in the question what's wrong with read-only method. That's, my requirement is not to make the textbox accept no key at all! It has to accept key strokes, but it should restrict those keys which makes the textbox editable(alphabets,numbers,backspace,enter).Hope you got my point.That is, I want my textbox to accept `Control` and `Control + R` and `Escape`shortcuts. If i press these keys, it should do something from the textbox. IF i make the textbox readonly it accepts only Control and escape, not Control +R...

Comment: Furthermore, Control + R wont be registered at all since keydown of Control is first registered which I commented under your post

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> keys won't work if the textbox is set to ReadOnly, as you suggested early on in the question that you had done. Make sure the property is still set to true. You can either set it in the Properties window, or through code like so:

```
myTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
```

Then, you need to handle the `KeyDown` event for the textbox control, and watch for the specific keys that you're interested in. Something like this:

```
private void myTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Control)
   {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.R)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Pressed Ctrl+R");
      }
      else
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Pressed Ctrl");
      }
   }
   else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Pressed Esc");
   }
}
```

This works exactly as expected, as long as the textbox is set to read-only. No other keys are recognized, and the user cannot change or modify any of the text in the textbox. You don't need to suppress the keypresses, as the control is already doing that when you set it to read-only. You also don't need to handle both the `KeyDown` and `KeyPress` events. `KeyPress` won't work for you anyway, as it doesn't let you handle control characters.

Comment: I'm thankful you chipped in. Your answers were helpful before. The problem with this code is that Contol+R wont work at all considering always "Pressed Ctrl" message is first shown. There's no way here to register Ctrl+R since "only" Ctrl is registered and is always first registered. Hope you get it

Comment: @nawfal: Right, it doesn't work with a messagebox. That was for testing purposes only. It's fixable, though, if that matters to you. I just copied the code from your question.

Comment: yes that's ok I can understand. I know that messageboxes are a bit different. But somehow what I want to do (executing processes, killing processes etc) too dont get executed much like messageboxes as in this case. The ` e.SuppressKeyPress` worked fine

Comment: @nawfal: There's more than one way to skin a cat. It's much easier to answer your questions, though, if you're clear about all the requirements up front. `e.Handled` or `e.SuppressKeyPress` will certainly work, too. (By the way, I approved your edit on the accepted answer; not sure why two others rejected it.)